# Jquery UI progress bar, need to show after form submit (php and jquery)

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I have a problem involving Jquery UI progress bar and PHP. This is the scenario,

1) user selects some fields in a html form which is then posted using php

2) Data is retrived from the post, this data can be large enough for the page to take a few minutes to load (hence the reason why im implementing a progress bar)

3) while the page loads the Jquery UI progress bar incrases progress.

So far I have installed the jquery progress bar, but it only appears while the page has loaded, not while it is in the progress of loading.

Any help?

This is a sample of my source code

```
 <?php

 echo "<div id='progress-bar'></div>";
 if (isset($_POST['submit']))   {

 if(!empty($_POST['startdate']) && !empty($_POST['enddate']))   {


        $accountdetails = GetAccountDetails("SELECT Account_Name,         Account_Project_X, Account_Number FROM Accounts WHERE Account_Name = '".$_POST['accountnames']."'"); 
        echo "<div id='data-table'>";

   ?>
```

The data table contains the data which will be loaded,

Then the data table div ends and then the file references to css and jquery files are added along with the javascript code to the progress bar.

```
  <link type="text/css" href="css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css"    rel="Stylesheet" />    
  <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="Stylesheet" />    

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"></script>



 <script    type="text/javascript">
 $('#startdate').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
 $('#enddate').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
 </script>

 <script    type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#progress-bar").progressbar();
});
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding, when the form is posted; the page reloads (the usual PHP way).
To make use of the progressbar, a few things need to be taken into consideration:

1. The content to be `POST`ed needs to be `POST`ed using jQuery (i.e. using AJAX)
2. You need to have a method to identify the amount of content loaded as well as the amount remaining in order to know by what quantity to update the progressbar

If those are done, then you should be able to get it working

Comment: The data is retrieved from Google via CURL, this is why the page takes so long to load.